# Using dfshim.dll to control ClickOnce applications in unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, dll, clickonce

I just found out that there is a minimal unmanaged API for ClickOnce applications in windows that is located in `dfshim.dll`. Unfortunately I could only find a very incomplete documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629396.aspx

There are only very few references in the web. All of them are using the DLL by executing command lines to call the DLL's functions using rundll32.exe.

I would like to call the DLL's functions from C++ code. I did not find a header file to include or a stub-file to link.

I could explicitely load the DLL during runtime and resolve the function symbols manually but that seems pretty uncommon for a Windows API. Also I would need to guess the signature for many of the functions.

How can I use that DLL with Visual Studio 2013? Why is there no include file? Is this actually an official/public API?

Answer (score 3):

Strange, this code is hardly documented.

we ended up in this code:

```
bool    LaunchClickOnceApplication(LPCSTR pszApplication)
{
HRESULT hr(-1);

HINSTANCE hInst = ::LoadLibrary("dfshim.dll");
if ( hInst )
{
    typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *dfshim_LaunchApplicationProc) (LPCWSTR pszApplication, LPVOID pData, DWORD dwFlags);

    dfshim_LaunchApplicationProc fnLaunch = (dfshim_LaunchApplicationProc)GetProcAddress(hInst, "LaunchApplication");
    if ( fnLaunch )
    {
        hr = fnLaunch(CA2W(pszApplication), NULL, 0);
    }
    ::FreeLibrary(hInst);
    return SUCCEEDED(hr);
}
else
{
    DWORD dwErr = ::GetLastError();
    char szMsg[128];
    _snprintf_s(szMsg, sizeof(szMsg), _TRUNCATE, "Cannot load dfshim.dll: %lu", dwErr);
    AfxMessageBox(szMsg);
    return false;
}
}
```

It is kind of unprofessional not to rely on documentation. It it more like a hack, but I don't see an alternative way. This code works for us.

Comment: The only documentation I could find is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-unmanaged-api-reference?view=vs-2022#launchapplication